# Windows 10 UWP: Lock Screen Numeric Badge Notification

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to add a badge(numeric) notification to the lock screen but I haven't had much luck. Any help with this would be much appreciated!!!

```
var badgeContent = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeNumber);
BadgeNotification badgeNotification = new BadgeNotification(badgeContent);
BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badgeNotification);
```

Comment: What is your issue with this code? Is there an exception? Or does the notification not appear? Have you added the app on your lock screen in the system settings?

Comment: There isn't any exception thrown and I am getting the fly out notification and I have manually added the app to the lock screen in the system setting but the lock screen badge does not update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the displayed number:

```
XmlElement lockScreenNumber = badgeContent.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as XmlElement;
lockScreenNumber.SetAttribute("value", 5);
                                    /* ^ or any number except 0 - 0 will hide the badge */
```

Insert this between your 1st and 2nd line of code, then it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to get the content of the lockscreen badge if it's already set? For example, the badge has been set and showing 5 notications. It there a way to check this value accordingly for newly incoming notifications and to clear it it notifications has been "read" or viewed?

Comment: You have to keep track of your notifications (i.e. read status) and update the number accordingly, not vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've all over msdn couldn't any example of how to get a count of all current notifications. Could you possibly post an example or post link to an example?